# Validate a Shopify Gift Card

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

So, I researched Shopify API docs and found the [admin resource](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2022-04/resources/gift-card#resource-object) for Gift Cards, which enables store owners to create/list/update Gift Cards.

But what I'm trying to find is the API that can validate a Shopify Gift Card through its code, that belongs to anyone.

I know I can do this in Shopify Checkout where I can input the code and it will add the code to the checkout if it's a valid code.

Is there a way to do this through an API? If Shopify doesn't have this API, is there any online service for this?

Comment: What kind of validation you want to perform on a gift card?

Comment: Whether it's a valid code or not.

Comment: When you fetch the gift card, it return the balance, expire date, and user id etc. I think which is enought to know the status of a gift card.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify does not provide a specific API endpoint for validating gift card codes. The Shopify API primarily focuses on store management and administration tasks.

To validate a gift card code, you would typically need to implement custom logic within your application. Here's a general approach you can follow:

1. Retrieve the gift card information
2. Iterate through the list of gift cards and compare the input code
   with the codes of the gift cards you retrieved.
3. If you find a match, consider it a valid gift card code.

Keep in mind that you'll need to handle the validation logic on your end.